# Let $\phi:A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, $\phi^{*}:Y\to X$ the induced continuous map on $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A), Y=\mathrm{Spec}(B)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is from Atiyah and MacDonald, Exercise 1.21, part iii).

We let $Z=\mathrm{Spec}(R)=\{\mathfrak{p}\subset R\mid\mathfrak{p}\mathrm{\,a\,prime \,ideal}\}$ have the Zariski topology, i.e. with closed sets $V(E)\,\forall \,E\subseteq R$, where $V(E)$ is the set of all prime ideals that contain $E$. Consequentially, $Z$ has $\{Z_f\mid f\in R\},\, Z_f=Z\setminus V(f)$ as topological basis. We let $\phi^{*}(\mathfrak{q})=\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$, and it can be proved that $\phi^{*}$ is continuous.

Let $\mathfrak{b}\subset B$ be an ideal, then I wish to show that $\overline{\phi^{*} (V(\mathfrak{b}))} = V(\mathfrak{b}^c)$. I managed to prove that $\phi^{*} (V(\mathfrak{b}))\subseteq V(\mathfrak{b}^c)$, which implies $\overline{\phi^{*} (V(\mathfrak{b}))}\subseteq V(\mathfrak{b}^c)$, but I'm finding it tricky to prove the converse.

I know that $\phi^{*} (V(\mathfrak{b}))=\{\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})\mid\mathfrak{b}\subseteq\mathfrak{q}\}$, and $X$ has basis elements of the form $X_f = X\setminus V(f)$, so if I can prove that $\forall\mathfrak{p}$ s.t. $f\notin\mathfrak{p}$, there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$ s.t. $\mathfrak{b}\subseteq\mathfrak{q},\,\,f\notin\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$, but I can't see how to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\phi^*\,V(\mathfrak b)$ is contained in a Zariski closed set of $X = \text{Spec}(A)$, say $V(\mathfrak a)$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a$ of A. We will show that $V(\mathfrak \phi^{-1} \mathfrak b)\subseteq V(\mathfrak a)$, and this clearly implies the desired. Considering the preimage under $\phi^*$, one finds that

$$V(\mathfrak b)\subseteq (\phi^*){^{-1}}\phi^*\,V(\mathfrak b) \subseteq V(\phi(\mathfrak a)),$$
where we have used part ii of the exercise. It follows that $\phi(\mathfrak a)\subseteq \mathfrak r (\mathfrak b)$, hence $\mathfrak a\subseteq \phi^{-1}\mathfrak r(\mathfrak b) = \mathfrak r (\phi^{-1} \mathfrak b)$. Now apply $V$ on both sides.